# Beamer: add a content in the background of all pages

Tags: beamer

To write a library I need to run a code on all slides of a beamer document (to add some pdf annotations without changing the spacing). The problem is that I can’t do:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}{my code}
```

as it will be erased by the user on the next `\setbeamertemplate`. I tried to do:

```
\patchcmd\ps@empty
{\usebeamertemplate***{background}}
{\usebeamertemplate***{background}my code}
{}
{}

\patchcmd\ps@navigation
{\usebeamertemplate***{background}}
{\usebeamertemplate***{background}my code}
{}
{}
```

but I don’t know why it does not work. Any idea what I’m missing?

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{I want this text to be on all slide, even if the user resets the background template}

\begin{frame}
  Hello
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{My title}
  Hello
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{}
\begin{frame}
  Hello
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{My title}
  Hello
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

edit: I’m realizing that I need to do:

```
\patchcmd\@oddhead
{\usebeamertemplate***{background}}
{\usebeamertemplate***{background}my code}
{}
{}
```

instead… but I’m curious to hear if you have better alternative than patching beamer.

Comment: If you can't trust the user to not overwrite the background template, can you trust them to not redefine whatever element you choose to add your code?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz oh it’s not it term of security, just that the user might want to redefine the background template for its own purpose (e.g. add a background), but I don’t want this to remove my code as it would break functionalities.

Comment: There are may other layers you could use instead of the background https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqSwu.png

Comment: Oh, nice picture! Well, I’d prefer to avoid interfering with any code the user might want to use. Ideally, beamer should propose some hooks…